# Changing autorefname commands (e.g. \itemautorefname ) to '' (empty string) still inserts whitespace

Tags: spacing, hyperref, cross-referencing, lists

I'm using hyperref's `\autoref{}` to refer to labelled items of an enumeration. By default, references are displayed as "look at *item X*". I would like it rather to say "look at *X*".

I redefine `\itemautorefname` to be empty with:

```
\renewcommand{\itemautorefname}{}
```

Which removes the word "item", but leaves extra space.

```
\renewcommand{\itemautorefname}{}

\begin{enumerate}
...
\item \label{T:myitem} foo
...
\end{enumerate}
...

% just to compare \ref vs \autoref
Do \autoref{T:myitem} with \ref{T:myitem}.\\
Do 3 with 3. \\
```

Shows up as:

[image: example output]

How do I trim the superfluous leading space?

**update: why not just `\ref{}`**

One may (and one did) point out that it may be simpler to use `\ref{}` in this case to produce the desired output. My insistence on using `\autoref` is moot. I've simply formed the habit of using `\autoref{}` everywhere to explicitly not have to worry about the type of thing I'm referencing. It eases refactoring if I change my mind and then want to prefix all item references to "Rule" or something else later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\autoref` uses (after loading some macros and expansion)

`\itemautorefname\space` in the end.

If `\itemautorefname` is defined to do nothing, the `\space` is still active, but this can be removed by `gobbling` it, i.e. a 'ghost' macro that absorbs the following token to be an argument, in this case use `\@gobble`.

Since `\@gobble` is an '@'-letter command, the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair is needed in a document.

Now, the final question is: Why using `autoref` here when `\ref` would do the same? ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\itemautorefname}{\@gobble}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{T:myitem} foo
\end{enumerate}

Do \autoref{T:myitem} with \ref{T:myitem}.
Do 3 with 3. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm. I will update my question concerning the use of `\ref` vs `\autoref`. Out of curiosity, would you mind writing a sentence or two about how one would typically go about exploring the expansion of commands. e.g. Do you inspect intermediate results of compilation, or just go directly to the source files of the package -- what's faster.

Comment: @init_js: Actually, it is a matter of experience -- there are some commands which are pretty clear how they are defined, other ones have to be looked after. There are basically two approaches here, which can be applied: Visit the source file(s) and (not mutually exclusive!) using either the `\show\foo` or `\meaning\foo` commands which give an idea how the command is setup. The last way however does work recursively in the sense that the context of the command is printed, which other commands are necessary.