# changing autorefnames inserts space in header

Tags: scrlayer-scrpage, autoref

I use `hyperref` and `autoref`, but redefine the autorefnames. I'm putting chapter and section names into my page-headers using `scrlayer-scrpage`. There's some unwanted space, always on the left side in the headline ... doesn't matter if I'm on even or odd page. It's especially apparent when chapter or section names are too long to fit into the headline. In the example, they could in principle fit, but don't, because of the space.

If I don't rename the `autoref`s, everything is fine. What's going on here, and how can I fix it?

I've tried ["gobbling"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328706/changing-autorefname-commands-e-g-itemautorefname-to-empty-string-stil), before and after the new `\...autorefname`, but that doesn't help.

```
\documentclass[pdfa,a4paper,
               11pt,
               bibliography=totoc,
               numbers=noenddot,
               twoside,openright,
               parskip=half]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% ********************************************************************
% Languages, Typesetting
% ******************************************************************** 
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         %windows: latin9, linux: utf8

% ********************************************************************
% page layout
% ********************************************************************
\usepackage[]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{empty} % no headings or footings on first chapter page
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{{#1}}{{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\upshape{\thesection}\enspace{#1}}}
\lehead{\mbox{\llap{\small\upshape\thepage\kern2em}\scshape\headmark\hfil}}
\rohead{\mbox{\hfil{\scshape\headmark}\rlap{\small\kern2em\upshape\thepage}}}
\chead{}\ifoot{}\cfoot{}\ofoot{}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

% ********************************************************************
% Hyperreferences, always load last
% ********************************************************************
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
% Commenting this whole block fixes the problem
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{babel}
{
    \addto\extrasenglish{
        \renewcommand*{\figureautorefname}{Figure}
        \renewcommand*{\tableautorefname}{Table}
        \renewcommand*{\partautorefname}{Part}
        \renewcommand*{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}
        \renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{Section}
        \renewcommand*{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}
        \renewcommand*{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Section}
        \renewcommand*{\appendixautorefname}{Appendix}
    }
}{\relax}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\part{Intro}
\chapter{Short chapter name}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Short section name}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{Very long chapter name just not fitting into the headline}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Very long section name just not fitting into the headline}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried ` \addto\extrasenglish{%` ?

Comment: I did in the full document ... where it didn't work. Guess I'm going to start crazy, now it works. What would happen to the autorefnames in the German part of the document (I don't need autorefs there, just curious)?

Comment: Well, `babel` switches to German and won't use the `\extrasenglish` setup, most likely, so I don't expect those spaces then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
\AfterPackage*{babel}
{
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\figureautorefname}{Figure}
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\tableautorefname}{Table}
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\partautorefname}{Part}
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\sectionautorefname}{Section}
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Section}
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\appendixautorefname}{Appendix}
}
```

`\AfterPackage*` is defined by package `scrlfile` which is loaded by the KOMA-Script classes automatically. `\renewcaptionname` is a KOMA-Script command too.

Additionally I would change the settings for the page layout to

```
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{empty} % no headers or footers on first chapter page
\usepackage[]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\automark*[section]{}
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{}% no chapter number in header/footer
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\scshape}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\small}
\clearmainofpairofpagestyles
\lehead{\mbox{\llap{\pagemark\kern2em}\headmark}}
\rohead{\mbox{{\ifstr{\leftmark}{\rightmark}{}{\upshape}\headmark}\rlap{\kern2em\pagemark}}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[pdfa,a4paper,
               11pt,
               bibliography=totoc,
               numbers=noenddot,
               twoside,openright,
               parskip=half]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% ********************************************************************
% Languages, Typesetting
% ******************************************************************** 
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% ********************************************************************
% page layout
% ********************************************************************
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{empty} % no headers or footers on first chapter page
\usepackage[]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\automark*[section]{}
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{}%  no chapter number in header/footer
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\scshape}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\small}
\clearmainofpairofpagestyles
\lehead{\mbox{\llap{\pagemark\kern2em}\headmark}}
\rohead{\mbox{{\ifstr{\leftmark}{\rightmark}{}{\upshape}\headmark}\rlap{\kern2em\pagemark}}}

% ********************************************************************
% Hyperreferences, always load last
% ********************************************************************
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\AfterPackage*{babel}
{
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\figureautorefname}{Figure}
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\tableautorefname}{Table}
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\partautorefname}{Part}
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\sectionautorefname}{Section}
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Section}
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\appendixautorefname}{Appendix}
}

\begin{document}
\part{Intro}
\chapter{Short chapter name}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Short section name}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{Very long chapter name just not fitting into the headline}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Very long section name just not fitting into the headline}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update:** Another example regarding a comment:

```
\documentclass[pdfa,a4paper,
               11pt,
               bibliography=totoc,
               numbers=noenddot,
               twoside,openright,
               parskip=half]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% ********************************************************************
% Languages, Typesetting
% ******************************************************************** 
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{textcase}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\textls[80]{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}
% ********************************************************************
% page layout
% ********************************************************************
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{empty} % no headers or footers on first chapter page
\usepackage[]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\automark*[section]{}
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{}%  no chapter number in header/footer
\renewcommand*\sectionmarkformat{{\small\thesection\autodot\enskip}}% section number using \small
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\small}% page number using \small
\clearmainofpairofpagestyles% remove all default entries for page style scrheadings
\lehead{\mbox{\llap{\pagemark\kern2em}\spacedlowsmallcaps{\headmark}}}
\rohead{\mbox{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\headmark}\rlap{\kern2em\pagemark}}}

% ********************************************************************
% Hyperreferences, always load last
% ********************************************************************
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\AfterPackage*{babel}
{
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\figureautorefname}{Figure}
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\tableautorefname}{Table}
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\partautorefname}{Part}
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\sectionautorefname}{Section}
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Section}
  \renewcaptionname{english}{\appendixautorefname}{Appendix}
}

\begin{document}
\part{Intro}
\chapter{Short chapter name}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Short section name}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{Very long chapter name just not fitting into the headline}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Very long section name just not fitting into the headline}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Note that you can not use `\MakeTextLowercase` in `\setkomafont` or `\addtokomafont`. Therefore you have to insert `\spacedlowsmallcaps` in `\lehead` any `\rohead`.

Comment: Your solution works as well. I've tried to incorporate the settings for the page layout, because they look much cleaner than mine. Didn't manage though, because the full document tries to mimick the feel of `classicthesis`. I'm reformatting the chapter and section names to be all lowercase and then set them in small caps by defining: `\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\textls[80]{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}%` (needs `microtype` and `textcase`). I call `\spacedlowsmallcaps` when I renew the chapter/sectionmark and I wasn't sure how to squeeze that into your `\automark`

Comment: I have added an additional example with your `\spacedlowsmallcaps`.

Comment: Just noted that your solution also fixed the capitalization in the headline of contents and bibliography. Awesome! I'm not sure what best practice is now ... but I've changed the accepted answer. Even though that was technically not the original question ;)

Comment: @Wiebke ... Indeed, the fix of headline etc. was not in your question and is another issue.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I understand that ... but how would I then honor the extra mile esdd went here to help?

Answer (score 3):

Any of the `\renewcommand*{\....autorefname}{...}` statements will cause an extra space character since it is done within `\extraenglish` which is called during typesetting and not in the preamble already.

Add a `%` at the end of each of those lines.

```
\documentclass[pdfa,a4paper,
               11pt,
               bibliography=totoc,
               numbers=noenddot,
               twoside,openright,
               parskip=half]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% ********************************************************************
% Languages, Typesetting
% ******************************************************************** 
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         %windows: latin9, linux: utf8

% ********************************************************************
% page layout
% ********************************************************************
\usepackage[]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{empty} % no headings or footings on first chapter page
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{{#1}}{{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\upshape{\thesection}\enspace{#1}}}
\lehead{\mbox{\llap{\small\upshape\thepage\kern2em}\scshape\headmark\hfil}}
\rohead{\mbox{\hfil{\scshape\headmark}\rlap{\small\kern2em\upshape\thepage}}}
\chead{}\ifoot{}\cfoot{}\ofoot{}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

% ********************************************************************
% Hyperreferences, always load last
% ********************************************************************
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
% Commenting this whole block fixes the problem
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{babel}
{
  \addto\extrasenglish{%
    \renewcommand*{\figureautorefname}{Figure}%
    \renewcommand*{\tableautorefname}{Table}%
    \renewcommand*{\partautorefname}{Part}%
    \renewcommand*{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}%
    \renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{Section}%
    \renewcommand*{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}%
    \renewcommand*{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Section}%
    \renewcommand*{\appendixautorefname}{Appendix}%
  }%
}{\relax}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\part{Intro}
\chapter{Short chapter name}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Short section name}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{Very long chapter name just not fitting into the headline}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Very long section name just not fitting into the headline}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```